# dependency not found core-js/modules/es.typed-array.at.js while upgrading quasar inside upgrading vue 2 to vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I was trying to upgrade quasar framework from quasar 1 to quasar 2 which is based on vue 3 where previous version was based on vue 2

not finding any trace of the error

[console of quasar dev dependency not found core-js/modules/es.typed-array.at.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PoRE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, I just need to install core-js package.
but i couldn't think of core-js.

Because this project is running as it is (without core-js) for a very long time no problem happend, i found the error just after upgrading the project.

So i thought it was quasar 2 upgrade problem but its not.

Core js added in quasar at some point, most probably my project is not needed to use that package anywhere that's why I didn't see any error till now.